# How to search for page/category in Wikimedia Commons by API?

Tags: mediawiki-api, wikimedia-commons

I want to be able to query Wikimedia commons to be able to find a page or category.

Naïvely I thought https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srsearch=Albert%20Einstein would do, however as you can see it does not return the page I want ([Albert Einstein](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Albert_Einstein)).

Also is there any way to restrict the search to only return categories? For example: [Category: Albert Einstein](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Albert_Einstein)

**EDIT**: I figured out what I wanted, this will give back categories and pages.

https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=search&prop=info&gsrsearch=Albert%20Einstein&gsrnamespace=14|0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default your query returns only 10 results, so add **[srlimit=500](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Bsearch)** in your request and you will see Albert Einstein.

```
https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srsearch=Albert%20Einstein&srlimit=500
```

To restrict the search to only return categories you need to use **[srnamespace=14](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:Namespaces)**:

```
https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srsearch=Albert%20Einstein&srlimit=500&srnamespace=14
```

Comment: Actually now I just realized the query I wrote did have Albert Eistein as the first result.  It's just that I was expecting a page id, would you know how to get the page_id returned?  The api docs https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Bsearch don't mention anything.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out, thanks for your help though :)

Comment: PageID you can get with generator: https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=search&gsrsearch=Albert%20Einstein